# How to Explicitly convert data type while inserting data into MS-SQL from external system?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I tried inserting data into column from extrenal system but it is returning the nvarchar format data, where as the data  is actually in Numeric format.

hence the data is being lost as it is automatically converted to Exponential format.
No way to convert the data type from this external system.

Is it possible that at the point of insertion of the data into my MS-SQL db it should again cinverted to Numeric format?

Comment: How are you inserting the data? Show us some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The External system is a Data extraction tool for Salesforce called Apex data loader. its due to Salesforce limitation during the extraction of Numeric field with more than 8 digits, converts automatically to exponential notation and the same data is inserted into the MS-SQL Db which is actually not the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by external system?

Say for example, it is MS Excel spreadsheet, you still can use the native t-sql functions to convert the data type of the columns. And that too should be the case with most of the external data.

```
SELECT Name, Age, convert(decimal(5,2), Amount) FROM OPENQUERY (XLSX_NewSheet, 'Select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

or

```
SELECT Name, Age, convert(decimal(5,2), Amount) FROM XLSX_NewSheet...[Sheet1$]
```

Where `Name`, `Age` and `Amount` are Excel sheet's column header names

Comment: The External system is a Data extraction tool for Salesforce called Apex data loader. its due to Salesforce limitation during the extraction of Numeric field with more than 8 digits , converts automatically to expoenetial notaion and the same data is inserted into the MS-SQl Db which is actually not the correct data.